Replace Prediction Head for XLM-RoBERTa-Base
I want to replace the XLM-RoBERTa-Base prediction head for a NER task (9 tags) with the weights for very specific words. For example, for the NER tag "B-PER" I would like to use the weights from the XLM-RoBERTa vocabulary for the word "George". The words for the individual labels look like this:
labels = ["I-PER", "B-PER", "I-LOC", "B-LOC", "I-ORG", "B-ORG", "I-MISC", "B-MISC", "O"]
tag_prediction = {"I-PER": "Miller",
                  "B-PER": "George",
                  "I-LOC": "Jersey",
                  "B-LOC": "Paris",
                  "I-ORG": "The",
                  "B-ORG": "FC",
                  "I-MISC": "Cup",
                  "B-MISC": "World",
                  "O": "by"}

However, if I now evaluate my new model, I get very bad results:
('eval_loss': 5.455610752105713, 'eval_precision': 0.017951501990589938, 'eval_recall': 0.043909348441926344, 'eval_f1': 0.02548425217078559, 'eval_accuracy': 0.02312910520081835)

Even if I pass a perfect example sentence such as "George Miller lives in New Jersey", all words are classified incorrectly here. All words are classified as "I-PER".
Here is my code, which extracts the weights from XLM-RoBERTa:
import torch
from transformers import XLMRobertaForTokenClassification, XLMRobertaTokenizer
import os

# Load model and tokenizer
model = XLMRobertaForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base", num_labels=9)
tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base")
print(model)

# Define labels and their most common prediction
labels = ["I-PER", "B-PER", "I-LOC", "B-LOC", "I-ORG", "B-ORG", "I-MISC", "B-MISC", "O"]
tag_prediction = {"I-PER": "Miller",
                  "B-PER": "George",
                  "I-LOC": "Jersey",
                  "B-LOC": "Paris",
                  "I-ORG": "The",
                  "B-ORG": "FC",
                  "I-MISC": "Cup",
                  "B-MISC": "World",
                  "O": "by"}

# Convert words to token IDs
token_ids = {}
for label in labels:
    name = tag_prediction[label]
    encoded_ids = tokenizer.encode(name, add_special_tokens=False)
    token_ids[label] = encoded_ids

# Save old weights/biases
old_weights = model.classifier.weight.detach().clone()
old_bias = model.classifier.bias.detach().clone()

# Output the old weights and biases for each output feature
for idx, label in enumerate(labels):
    weight = old_weights[idx].detach().numpy()
    bias = old_bias[idx].item()
    print(f"{label}:")
    print(f"  Weight: {weight[0:10]}")
    print(f"  Bias: {bias}")

# Initialize new weights/biases
new_weights = old_weights.clone()
new_bias = old_bias.clone()

# Replace weights/bias of the tags with those of the specific words (e.g.: Replace weights/bias of 'B-PER' with 'John')
for label in labels:
    ids = token_ids[label]
    idx = labels.index(label)
    for token_id in ids:
        new_weights[idx] = model.roberta.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight[token_id].detach()
        new_bias[idx] = 0

# Insert weights/biases into model
model.classifier.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(new_weights)
model.classifier.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(new_bias)

Any tips or advice?

are you finetuning your model? classifier weights are random when you construct the model.

No, I am not fine-tuning the model on any labeled data. Instead, I load the base model, swap the weights for each label, save the model, load the saved model and evaluate it directly.

Your assumption is already wrong. Why should the contextualized embeddings of the tokens be similar (in the sense of a distance metric) to the non-contextualized token embeddings? The model wasn't trained for that and has therefore no reason to align the contextualized vectors to the token vectors. Compare this StackOverflow answer.
